# Achieving File Upload Synchronization from MinIO S3 to CKAN

Tags: minio, ckan

I've successfully set up CKAN integrated with MinIO S3 for file storage. Presently, when files are uploaded within CKAN, they reflect in the associated MinIO S3 bucket. However, I'm curious about the feasibility of the reverse process: is it possible for files uploaded directly into the MinIO S3 bucket to automatically reflect or sync within the CKAN application?